# netlogo-headless.sh does not run on SSH instance on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, netlogo, behaviorspace

When running:

```
    netlogo-headless.sh --model abc.nlogo --experiment experiment --table -
```

on an SSH instance on Google cloud, I get the error:
-bash:netlogo-headless.sh: command not found

When runnning the above prefixed by 'sh', I get the following errors:

```
    netlogo-headless.sh: 3: netlogo-headless.sh: Bad subsitution
    netlogo-headless.sh: 5: netlogo-headless.sh: [[: not found
    netlogo-headless.sh: 14: netlogo-headless.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have not made any changes to the netlogo-headless.sh file. 
I have set JAVA_HOME in .profile and .bashrc . However, JAVA_HOME and PATH still do not point to the jdk installation directory. Any ideas if this is the problem and/or there some other environment variables I should be setting?

The command runs fine when I run it from Google Shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"netlogo-headless.sh: command not found" indicates that the directory containing the file `netlogo-headless.sh` isn't in your `PATH` environment variable.

The simplest solution would probably be to replace `netlogo-headless.sh` with `./netlogo-headless.sh` (if the script is in your current working directory) or with a full absolute path. (Adding the directory containing the script to your `PATH` would work too, but seems like overkill.)

Running the script with `sh` won't work because is bash script. Replacing `sh` with `bash` would probably make it work.